# Using SpringBoot as an application loader

Tags: spring-boot

I have a spring-boot app that acts as a small framework for other apps. It provides a couple of JMS queues and a DAO layer to retrieve and store data from a common set of data stores. The problem is that the original developer of this framework app is scanning all the package "com.mycompany" (rather than com.mycompany.framework) so that it can load the beans of the specific app that may be declared under com.mycompany.myapp1 or com.mycompany.myapp2 an which JARs are bundled together with the JARs of the framework.

We only load a single app in the JVM (app1 or app2), but these apps may share other libraries and sometimes we end up with beans in the context that we don't need. (these may be needed in app1 but not in app2)
So, what would be your advice ?

My problem is similar to what was described here:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/3300

I am debating if each app should be aware of the framework and load it. Or if the framework should instantiate a class loader and create a new Spring context loading the app specific code as suggested in the link above.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should consider leveraging some of Spring Boot's Auto Configuration capabilities such as `@ConditionalOnProperty` or  `@ConditionalOnClass` in your framework. That way, you can only actually enable certain beans if and when the application using your framework takes some specific action (e.g. has a given jar on the classpath, or sets a configuration value). For reference check out: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-developing-auto-configuration